# Cannot display value of php to html input form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I want to display array value on html. array value is from php.

select option is working , but next string value is not display.

like this picture...

[image]

( it doesn't work "getting value" ..i think....)

source code is here...

**PHP -**

```
<?php
   $arr[0]="11.1.35.132";
?>
```

php code has.. only array value.and that value is post to the HTML.

**HTML -**

```
    <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
<script type="text/javascript">

function getR() {
    document.forms['save']['cnt_mme'].value = "<?php echo count($arr); ?>";
    document.forms['save']['mmeremoteip'].value = <?php echo json_encode($arr[0]); ?>;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="getR();">
<form name="save" method="post">
<h1>TEST</h1>
<table>

<tr><td>No. of IP</td>
<td id="cnt_mme">
<script>
  var mmeip = "<?php echo count($arr); ?>";
  var opt = document.getElementById("cnt_mme");
  var html="<select size=\"1\"";

  for(i = 0; i < mmeip; i++) {
      html += "<option value=\"" + i + "\">" + i +"</option>";
  }
  html + "</select></td>";
  opt.innerHTML = html;
</script>
  <tr>
   <td class="param">Remote IP</td>
   <td><input type="text" class="inputParam" size="20" maxlength="15" name="mmeremoteip" id="MME REMOTE IP"></td>
  </tr>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**and view-source is ....**

```
   <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
<script type="text/javascript">

function getR() {
    document.forms['save']['cnt_mme'].value = "3";
    document.forms['save']['mmeremoteip'].value = "10.1.35.31";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="getR();">
<form name="save" method="post">
<h1>TEST</h1>
<table>

<tr><td>No. of MME Remote IP</td>
<td id="cnt_mme">
<script>
  var mmeip = "3";
  var opt = document.getElementById("cnt_mme");
  var html="<select size=\"1\"";

  for(i = 0; i < mmeip; i++) {
      html += "<option value=\"" + i + "\">" + i +"</option>";
  }
  html + "</select></td>";
  opt.innerHTML = html;
</script>
  <tr>
   <td class="param">MME Remote IP</td>
   <td><input type="text" class="inputParam" size="20" maxlength="15" name="mmeremoteip" id="MME REMOTE IP"></td>
  </tr>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I think getR() Function had a problem. I don't know exactly.

Comment: Where is your close `form` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.forms['save']['mmeremoteip'].value = <?php echo $arr[0]; ?>;
```

Don't encode it, there is no need.

Answer (score 0):

Here select tag is not closed and try to add more values in array that your are accessing in script.

for example add

```
<?php
$arr=array();

   $arr[0]="11.1.35.132";
    $arr[1]="11.1.35.133";
     $arr[2]="11.1.35.135";

?>
```

add change close the select tag in html:

```
<script>
  var mmeip = "<?php echo count($arr); ?>";
  var opt = document.getElementById("cnt_mme");
  alert(mmeip)
  var html="<select size=\"1\">";

  for(var i = 0; i < mmeip; i++) {
      html += "<option value="+ i + ">" + i +"</option>";
  }
  html + "</select></td>";
  opt.innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

you will get the option list with 0,1,2 option value.